# Trigger Azure Logic apps workflow when message received in Azure Queue

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-queues

Trying to create a Logic app workflow, which would get triggered when any messaged received in the Azure Queue storage.
While designing the workflow , trigger step do see the Azure queue option but dont see any triggers associated with it
Is this possible or need to switch to 'Service Bus' option which i do see the triggers
Any issues in accessing the queue from a Logic App workflow ?

Thanks
SAV

Comment: is it logic app standard or consumption ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***We have reproduced from our end ,You can do this with Azure Service Bus:***

[image]

***You can also do with Azure queue using Consumption Plan:***

[image]

Comment: i think it is the standard plan, will check on the consumption plan , thanks !!!